# How to scan the full DynamoDb table and get all the hashkey and paginate the result?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I need to fetch 100k productId from a table in DynamoDb where productId is the hash key. 
I am using *spring-data-dynamodb* dependency.

My questions are:

**How to get all the productIds from that table using CrudRepository?**

Is there any better method to get the productId rather than scan?

**Please suggest a way to paginate this 100k productId fetch? How to do it?**

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried - in the Python SDK you can start a scan operation and it will give you a continuation token if there are too many results. You can use this token on subsequent calls to paginate through all responses until no token is returned. I expect the Java SDK to do something similar.

Comment: You will need to perform some sort of scan unless you you build a custom stream-based solution that collects them as they are added. How frequently do you need to do this? Does the table have a sort key? If so, what’s the average number of sort key values per hash key?